# Calling map.fitBounds() Multiple Times in Google Maps API v3.0

Tags: google-maps, fitbounds

I've just begun using the Google Maps API (v3.0) and have had a good deal of success so far. I am loading a set of objects with Latitude & Longitude values from a database, passing them into my script, and looping over them in the script in order to add them to the map.

I am using the "`bounds.extend()` / `map.fitBounds()`" method of setting the map's zoom & bounds (see code below), which works as expected the first time around; however, if I clear out the existing markers, fetch another set of objects, and do the same thing *on the same map instance*, it sets the bounds incorrectly, usually resulting in a minimum zoom (an astronaut's view).

My suspicion is that my map object has some memory of the previous set of bounds that I've given it and that I need to find a way to clear these bounds before assigning my new ones, but I really can't be too sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
var locationList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < mapPoints.length; i++) { // mapPoints is a collection of DTOs
    var mapPoint = mapPoints[i];
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(mapPoint.Latitude, mapPoint.Longitude);
    locationList.push(location);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: '/Content/images/map/' + mapPoint.Status.Icon,
        shadow:  '/Content/images/map/shadow.png',
        position: location
    });
    markers.push(marker); // markers is an Array that is managed outside this loop
}

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var j = 0; j < locationList.length; j++) 
    bounds.extend(locationList[j]);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Do you clear out the `locationList` variable when you load a new set of markers?

Comment: `locationList` is initialized each time (first line in the code sample) and so is empty before the loop starts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This isn't the answer, so to speak, but a (slightly hacky) workaround that I discovered on a [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/7cdec95a29189f7c/d4a366f6dcb910ec?lnk=gst&q=fitbounds#d4a366f6dcb910ec) in the Google Maps Javascript API v3 group:

```
//map.fitBounds(bounds);
setTimeout( function() { map.fitBounds( bounds ); }, 1 );
```

Comment: The setTimeout or angular's $timeout waits for the current digest cycle to complete before executing, while I'm not exactly sure why this works, I'm guessing that some other process that clashes with fitBounds has yet to complete. A better option might be to listen for the completion event of that process, that is if you know what it is.

Comment: Works for me too. Weird.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use 100ms instead of 1ms to fix the problem. Besides, that gave me an interesting animation as a plus!

Answer (score 0):

if the above answer doesn't work for you (it didn't for me), the problem might lie in bootstrap (assuming you're using it). bootstrap modals specifically generate all sorts of wonky behaviour when i embed a map object in it.. curiously correcting itself if/when i drop an 'alert' in there..  in any case, i solved all my problems by just building my own modal (ie, not using bootstraps modals).